# If $L$ is the integral of $\dot x^2$, how do you find $\dot x(0)$ for when $L$ is minimal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

If $L$ is given by the equation above, I'm trying to find what $\dot x(0)$ is if i'm trying to minimize $L$. I tried

$$\dfrac{dL}{d \dot x} = 0 $$

for $L$ to be minimum. which gives the integral of $2\dot x$, and for this to $= 0$, $\dot x(0)$ must $= 0$. But I don't think that's correct?

Comment: I edited your question to make the $\LaTeX$ work.  Hope I got the content right!  If not, let me know!  Cheers!

Comment: Do we know anything else about $x(t)$ or its derivative?  Right now, you are asking to minimize the integral of a function whose only constraint is that it is the derivative of something else.  Your use of the letter "$L$" suggests you have a Lagrangian and/or are working in the context of calculus of variations and have an Euler-Lagrange equation, but you do not say so.

Comment: Also, don't sit in your office until twelve o'clock at night worrying about the WENUS.

Comment: oh thank you robert! I wasn't sure on how to do that. Also yes, actually, this is an ODE I'm trying to solve via numerical methods. But I'm trying to first find the initial conditions. I used either euler's method or runge kutta method to solve the ODEs but I'm trying to derive the initial condition first. I edited the question to show the original question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

This problem including the pendulum equation seems to be designed so that no symbolic solution is possible.

### Using function values and quadratic fit

To get an idea of the situation, just integrate to get a function table,

```
def derivs(state,t):
    x, vx, f, vf, L = state
    return [ vx, f-(0.1*vx+x+x**3), vf, -sin(f), vx**2 ]

def LT(v0):
    return odeint(derivs,[1,v0,0,0.5,0], [0,10], atol=1e-10, rtol=1e-12)[-1,4]

def plotL(a,b):
    m = 0.5*(a+b)
    print "m=%.15f"%m
    vs = linspace(a,b,301)
    Ls = [ LT(v0) for v0 in vs ]
    poly = polyfit(vs-m, Ls, 2)
    print "fitted quadratic %.15f*(x-m)^2+%.15f*(x-m)+%.15f"%(poly[0], poly[1], poly[2])
    print "minimum of quadratic = %.16f, value L=%.16f"%(m-poly[1]/(2*poly[0]), poly[0]-0.25*poly[1]**2/poly[0])
    plt.plot(vs,Ls,vs,(poly[0]*(vs-m)+poly[1])*(vs-m)+poly[2]); plt.show()

plotL(-2,3)
```

which gives output

```
[(0.53333333333333321, 2.8328919354789712)]

m=0.500000000000000
fitted quadratic 4.447957506793732*(x-m)^2+1.234022197401038*(x-m)+2.611850148318388
minimum of quadratic = 0.3612821507943574, value L=4.3623670542459854
```

and image

[image]

Further manual refinement proceeds up to `plotL(0.53955,0.539553)`

```
m=0.539551500000000
fitted quadratic 2.736707733437932*(x-m)^2+0.000000607084778*(x-m)+2.832786708021910
minimum of quadratic = 0.5395513890848354, value L=2.7367077334378984
```

[image]

but runs into problems with the accuracy of the numerical integration, points with values close to the minimum are found in the range `0.5395512,0.5395516`.

```
m=0.539551400000000
fitted quadratic 2.753718483322580*(x-m)^2+0.000000074235910*(x-m)+2.832786708021878
minimum of quadratic = 0.5395513865207880, value L=2.7537184833225794
```

[image]

### Using the derivative and a linear fit

It is usually easier to search for a root of the derivative which is usually approximately linear close to a minimum instead of searching with only the function values available, as the function locally very flat. Parametrize all relevant functions with the initial value $v$, $x=x(t,v)$, $L=L(v)$ for the solution with initial value $\dot x(0,v)=v$. Denote $D=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}$, $D\dot x=\dfrac{∂^2x}{∂v∂t}$ etc., especially $D\dot x(0)=1$. Then the derivatives of the original system are
\begin{align}
DL &= 2\int_0^T\dot x(t)D\dot x(t)\,dt\\
D\ddot x(t)&+0.1D\dot x(t)+Dx(t)+3x(t)^2Dx(t)=0\\
Dx_0&=0,
D\dot x_0=1
\end{align}

which can be evaluated similarly to the previous code as

```
def derivsD(state,t):
    x, vx, f, vf, L, Dx, Dvx, DL = state
    return [ vx, f-(0.1*vx+x+x**3), vf, -sin(f), vx**2,
             Dvx, -(0.1*Dvx+Dx+3*x**2*Dx), 2*vx*Dvx ]

def DLT(v0):
    return odeint(derivsD,[1,v0,0,0.5,0,0,1,0], [0,10], atol=1e-10, rtol=1e-12)[-1,[4,7]]

def plotDL(a,b):
    m = 0.5*(a+b)
    print "m=%.15f"%m
    vs = linspace(a,b,301)
    DLs = array([ DLT(v0) for v0 in vs ])
    poly = polyfit(vs-m, DLs[:,1], 1)
    poly0 = polyfit(vs-m, DLs[:,0], 2)
    print "linear fit %.15f*(x-m)+%.15f"%(poly[0], poly[1])
    s = -poly[1]/poly[0];
    L = (poly0[0]*s+poly0[1])*s+poly0[2];
    print "root of fit = %.16f, value L=%.16f"%(m+s,L)
    plt.plot(vs,DLs[:,1],vs,poly[0]*(vs-m)+poly[1]); plt.grid(); plt.show()

plotDL(0.5395512,0.5395516)
```

which gives output

```
m=0.539551400000000
linear fit 5.481046046001811*(x-m)+0.000000065623033
root of fit = 0.5395513880272795, value L=2.8327867090250209
```

with image

[image]

where the visual fit is perfect. To get numeric noise one needs to use a much tighter interval, such as `plotDL(0.53955138802725,0.53955138802731)`

```
m=0.539551388027280
linear fit 5.460965223325990*(x-m)+-0.000000000000021
root of fit = 0.5395513880272838, value L=2.8327867090250205
```

[image]

where one sees that with this method one can enclose the zero crossing no tighter than inside the interval `[0.53955138802727,0.53955138802729]`.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you did for part two. How did you derive everything with respect to  D ? Then after that, is the slope then ultimately the value of x˙(0)? Is it possible to integrate the function, and then find the lowest value?

Comment: The minimal value you get quite reliably using the first method. As you can see in the last graph, the uncertainty is about `1e-13` which is on par with the error tolerances of the numerical integration. Contrarily, the scale of the parameter $v=\dot x_0$ is `1e-7` in that graph. With the second method that is also reduced to `1e-13`. Or you could just integrate again. || Add $v=\dot x(0)$ as parameter everywhere and deliberately use the chain rule and commutativity of partial differentiation on $x=x(t,v)$, $L(v)$ etc.

Comment: How did you plot the x axis? when I integrated using trapezoidal method    sum = sum + h*(x_1(i+1)^2+x_1(i)^2)/2; where x_1 is x' and plot it to a linspace I get the following curve  https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ITk.png which doesn't have a minimum. Is my integral code incorrect?

Comment: I do not understand fully what you are drawing and what you are comparing it with. What is the x-axis? In my graphs it is always $v=\dot x(0)$, each point represents a different integration. By embedding $L$ into the system, its integration is also of order 4/5, like in the Simpson method.